# SCP via Python Subprocess Popen: "Identity File not accessible"

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, scp

When executing SCP from subprocess.popen I recieve the error: `Warning: Identity File ./id_rsa.key not accessible: no such file or directory.`  The problem is explained below.

I want to SCP a file from a local machine to a remote machine, using a python script, and I want to specify the key to use when executing SCP (using -i option).

My local machine is Windows 10 Enterprise.  My 'remote' machine is currently a Docker container running Alpine linux on my localhost.

When I run the command in an elevated shell, it works:

```
scp -i ./id_rsa.key -P 2222 ./test.plan root@127.0.0.1:/go/
```

When I execute the command via Python 3.6 subprocess.popen:

```
SSH = subprocess.Popen(['scp', '-i ./id_rsa.key', '-P 2222', './test.plan', 'root@127.0.0.1:/go/'],
    cwd = r'C:\ThePathToThisStuff',
    shell = False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

It prompts me for a password, `root@127.0.0.1's password:`, and when I enter the password it throws the error below, indicating that it fails to find the RSA key:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'> ERROR: [b'Warning: Identity file  ./id_rsa.key not accessible: No such file or directory.\n']
```

I've tried providing absolute paths to the keys, seperating each command in the arguments list into options and values, different groupings, etc.

Comment: `./id_rsa.key` is located in your current dir. What is that `print(os.getcwd())`? Also what's the name of your current user, and where did you get the *scp* executable?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in.  The accepted answer below solved this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not combine an option and its argument in the same parameter, they need to be separate list elements.

```
SSH = subprocess.Popen(['scp', '-i', './id_rsa.key', '-P', '2222', './test.plan', 'root@127.0.0.1:/go/'],
```

Comment: So, I've separated them, and it fails to parse.  I'll post the full output here  when I have a moment.

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect.  It does not fail to parse due to the separated command syntax, it was simply triggering another error that was getting buried.  This is the accepted answer.